# Variadic Macros need a unmeaningful macro to let it work?

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-macros

The following code is okay on VC++ 2012

```
#include <algorithm>    

#define MAX_OF_2(a,b)    std::max(a,b)
#define FOO(a)           a 

// work
#define MAX2(...)        FOO(MAX_OF_2(__VA_ARGS__)) 

// Not work
// #define MAX2(...)        MAX_OF_2(__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    int i = MAX2(1,2);
}
```

It cannot compile without using `FOO` macro. It shows not engough actual parameter for `MAX_OF_2`. Why or any bug on compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known [bug in msvc](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/380090/variadic-macro-replacement)

In your case `__VA_ARGS__` is considered as if it's a macro that needs expansion.